# Search of explicit type conversions in C style: a = (int)b;

Tags: c++, c, static-analysis

I have a question concerning the benefit of this diagnostic.
One user suggested that we implemented search of all the explicit type
conversions in C style in the PVS-Studio analyzer.
That is, a diagnostic to detect constructs of this kind:

```
int *x = (int *)y;
float a = float(b);
float c = (float)(d);
```

Its purpose is to replace all these conversions with their safer
versions - reinterpret_cast/static_cast/const_cast. During the process
of such refactoring, some defects in code may well be detected.

Of course, this is not detection of crucial errors, and if we
implement this diagnostic, it will be in the section [Customer's
Specific Requests] and disabled by default.

But I even doubt the benefit of this diagnostic. So I decided to ask
other users: does anybody else need this option of searching for explicit
type conversions in C style? Would anybody like to perform this kind
of refactoring in their code?

Comment: `float a = float(b);` is not a C-style cast. This syntax is introduced by C++.

Comment: @Nawaz But its semantics are *identical* to the C-style cast, and hence it has the same problems.

Comment: If your style guide says, "don't use C-style casts" then it would be useful to be able to enforce that in an automated way. Requiring the analysis to be free of this category of warning would achieve that, so it's useful to anyone who want to avoid them even if they aren't refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

A common view (e.g. [expressed by Stroustrup](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html)) is that C-style casts are apt to hide errors. I assume that these views would motivate quite a number of people not to use them, so a anti-C-cast diagnostic would get some usage, I guess. I personally wouldn't care to do it because I avoid C-style casts anyway, but given legacy code, I'd find the search useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would even go further, casts in general are a bad thing and code that uses them a lot is suspicious. This certainly the case for C, where the rules of implicit conversions that may happen is very limited and well defined by the language.

C++ is a bit more complicated because of overloading, but still, you shouldn't need much explicit casts. A design should always be such that there is one unique path to cast one type into another.

Cast are bad, because they easily hide problems if the type of the expression that is cast changes. In your example if `y` is changed from a pointer type to an integer type for example. But in any case C++ style casts are much better, be it alone that they are easier to search for, and that are really a pain to type, to people would naturally avoid them :) And just try to forbid `reinterpret_cast` completely or at least it should be really rare.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the motivation of C++ cast in favor of C cast (essentially because C cast are sometime static_cast, sometime reinterpret_cast, with risk of surprises) but ... refactoring something that already works may introduce even unexpected bugs, simply because you may misinterpret what the original developer was going to do...

Unless you are reconsidering rewriting the logic (so you are not working "statement by statement", but also understanding the overall semantics), I will not do it.

Comment: @KillianDS: yes of course! Especially if it is not "my" code, but something that is around from years, and already maintained by different developer with different styles. tools and library/compiler ages. There is sooner or later the time to reconsider the entire code, rather than "adjust" it. In that sanse is my post!

Answer (score 0):

> does anybody else need this option of searching for explicit type conversions in C style?

yes. it's an easy means to introduce/hide bugs (e.g. the most direct update of your program may produce some warnings or errors).

i favor cpp style casts because they are eyesores, while c style casts are easily obscured (that is by design).

better yet, going through the process and fixing the programs to be typesafe (most casting is unnecessary in cpp) is often a better solution.

> Would anybody like to perform this kind of refactoring in their code?

i got rid of all the old style casts and stuck with it along the way (some bugs as well). i am happier. depending on your codebase(s) and your level of trust of the developers that built it, it may not be a good use of time. it's a boring process, but time may end up being spent debugging the issues theta are masked (again, depends on the codebase).